# grid-list with diverse image sizes

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a bunch of images of **various sizes** (some wider than others, some taller etc).
How to make them fit nicely in an md-grid-list with material2 (Angular2)?
It is okay to crop the images so that it fills the grid tile (crop on screen, not crop the actual file). Preferably, the solution works for responsive layout (phone + desktop screen size), instead of a hard-coded image size.

```
<md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="200px">
  <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img [src]="image">
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```